Example of semi-stable non sufficiently smooth vector bundle
Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex variety and $H = c_1(\mathcal{O}_X(1))$ an ample class (if you prefer, you can take more generally $X$ to be a compact Kähler manifold with $H = [\omega]$ its Kähler class). When $E$ is a slope semi-stable vector bundle (the slope is computed with respect to $H$), it admits a Jordan-Hölder filtration by saturated (hence reflexive) sub-sheaves,
$$
0 = \mathcal{F}_0 \subsetneq \mathcal{F_1} \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \mathcal{F}_m = E,
$$
such that each $\mathcal{F}_k$ has the same slope as $E$ and each $\mathcal{G}_k = \mathcal{F}_k/\mathcal{F}_{k + 1}$ is slope stable. In particular the $\mathcal{F}_k$ are slope semi-stable. This filtration is not unique in general but the graded object of $E$,
$$
\mathrm{Gr}(E) = \bigoplus_{k = 1}^m \mathcal{G}_k,
$$
is unique up to isomorphism and is of course slope polystable. $E$ is said to be sufficiently smooth when $\mathrm{Gr}(E)$ is locally free i.e. a vector bundle.
Question : do you know examples of slope semi-stable vector bundles $E$ that are not sufficiently smooth ? It is folklore that semi-stability needs to be tested with respect to all sub-sheaves and not only sub-bundles so I guess we can find some $E$ that are stable with respect to sub-bundles but strictly stable with respect to sub-sheaves. Such an $E$ would be an example of a non sufficiently smooth semi-stable vector bundle.
More particularly, do you know an example of a Gieseker stable vector bundle (hence it is slope semi-stable) which is not sufficiently smooth ?
